# Why is my running time graph have outliers?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I implemented 3 algorithms, merge sort, insertion sort, and fast multiply. They all work correctly, I made extensive unit tests to confirm that. Now I am testing their running time over a large set of inputs of various sizes, but my graphs have outliers. What could be the causes?

The things I considered:

- My shuffling algorithm (move everything over by one. Then randomly swap 2 elements n times, where n = size of the array. This ensures very few elements remain in the same place and there is a decent amount of variation in each iteration)
- Random hardware stuff/ chance (would like a better explanation)

[merge sort running time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EfEt.jpg) , [fast multiply running time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iyiH.jpg)

I am refraining from posting the code since these are assignments and I do not want to get flagged for plagiarism.

Comment: On modern computers, for a number of reasons, the execution time of programs is non-deterministic and varies substantially. You can get better repeatability by running several times and taking the median measurement.

Comment: When the noise is one-sided (all of the random things that can happen in parallel with your test most likely slow it down), I usually reach for the min. Randomization makes it more complicated; I would average over the min for each input.